# GatsbyJS: Rebulding only specific pages

Tags: javascript, gatsby

I am wondering if its possible to tell the Gatsby process only to modify specific pages. The scenario could be:

You have a huge Blog with thousands of posts. For the initial build I get the contents via GraphQL API and create all /post/:postId pages for all my posts. As far as I understood GatsbyJS I have to rerun the build process when I want to change one or many of my posts. But: The building process is slow with many contents and it would be much easier to tell the build process hat Gatsby only has to modify the existing build. For example I only want to change the title of a post like this:

```
const newPage = { ...page };
deletePage(page);
createPage({
  ...newPage,
  context: {
    ...newPage.context,
    title: 'My new Blog title',
  },
});
```

Is there any way to tell gatsby only to rebuild the affected files instead of rebuilding everything?

The other solution would be to fetch the data always live from the graphql API on client but then I am loosing the SSR benefits and also the benefits of only serving static HTML files.

Answer (score 1):

What you describe is called **incremental builds**.

There is an [issue on the official Gatsby repo](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/5002#issuecomment-573461979) on github about your exact problem. It looks like the feature you need will be available in the next few releases:

> dominicfallows commented 18 days ago
>
> Just wanted to update that my team is close to publishing a PR into the Gatsby repo that we think enables incremental builds. We're just taking some time to write a good PR and tighten up the code, but I will update here when we are done (in the next week or so).

So the answer is:

### No, it is not possible yet.

But it will be possible in the next few weeks or months. As to how to implement it, you will need to wait for the official docs or look through the PR linked in the issue.

Comment: Thanks! Did not found this issue on github yet. I will subscribe it to be alerted when something new happend :)